# What to use for address and reference on direct debit form?

Tags: united-kingdom, direct-debit

I've been asked to complete a direct debit form from my HSBC account. Two of the fields are 'Address' and 'Reference', but I haven't got a clue which either should be.

I saw mention that reference might be my debit card number? And which address do they need - my branch or the HSBC UK HQ?

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. You shouldn't have to provide a Reference no for a Direct Debit, but you would for e.g. a Standing Order. Address would normally be your branch address.

Comment: @AndyT I'm not sure what doesn't make sense - I have a Direct Debit form that's asking me for an address and reference number

Comment: you could find the address on your bank statement.

Answer (score 4):

I have never had to fill in a reference number for a Direct Debit, anything like that would always (in my memory) have been pre-populated by the company who wants my money. But the only logical thing I can think is that the company has provided a blank form where you have to fill in all the fields. In this case your Reference must be something so that they can link the Direct Debit to your account *with the company* (note italics: I am not referring to your current account number). This must be something provided by the company on a bill or suchlike.

If you are unsure of what to put in the Reference field, contact the company in question. Make sure you get it right or they won't be able to take any money, and you will go into debt with them for unpaid bills.

By Address, I assume it is clear on the form that they want your bank's address? (It's not clear from your question). In that case, Address would normally be the branch address.

Answer (score 1):

Reference # usually is found on the bill and she be quoted in full. If you can't clearly tell what the reference number is try calling and having support direct you to it.

GL